# How to url-reverse the delete url for an item in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am testing my delete item API, but i cannot determine how to get the URL for the delete request.

I am using:

```
Django==1.11.13
 and 
djangorestframework==3.7.7
```

What is the right way to url_reverse for the DELETE request to `<api-path>/favorite-items/1/` ?

I am trying to url-reverse the delete of the item at:
`<api-path>/favorite-items/1/`.

`url.py` file:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'favorite_item', FavouriteItemAPI, base_name='favorite-items')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

i have tried:

```
    from model_mommy import mommy
    fav_item = mommy.make(FavouriteItem)
    view = FavouriteItemAPI()  # extends the Destroy mixin and has a destroy method
    url = view.reverse_action('destroy', args=[request_instance, fav_item.id])
```

as it is described in documentation at: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#reversing-action-urls

**Edit**:
What works is

```
    url =  '{}{}/'.format(url_reverse('favorite-items'), fav_item.id)
```

but doesn't look good at all

**Edit 2**:
What reads good seems to be:

```
    url = url_reverse('favorite-items-detail', kwargs={'pk':fav_item.id})
```

Any other options are welcomed

Comment: Where do you get "destroy"  description string?

Comment: after revising the question I see that I use the `destroy` method of the drf DestroyModelMixin to perform the DELETE request.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
url_reverse('favorite-items-detail', kwargs={"pk": fav_item.id})
```

with `DELETE` HTTP method.

Here is a useful url - method - action - name table from the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter).